# MySql timeout on large query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have searched this topic on SO and can't seem to find a solition. I am running a query that is timing out at about 7 sec. The error log on my hosted site is:

```
[21-Feb-2017 18:11:20 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: action in /home/public_html/county-vol.php on line 12
[21-Feb-2017 18:11:28 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/public_html/county-vol.php on line 22
[21-Feb-2017 18:11:28 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/public_html/county-vol.php on line 22
```

my script:

```
<?php
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","database","password","tech_training"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $query="SELECT u.UserName, u.LastName, u.Affiliation, (e.UserName IS NOT NULL) as completed 
            FROM UsersDataTbl u
            LEFT 
            JOIN EnrollmentsTbl e
            ON u.UserName = e.UserName 
            AND e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%' 
            WHERE u.Career = 0 AND u.Active = 1 ORDER BY u.LastName";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Vol Querystring Error");

    $json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($json );
?>
```

it only times out when I add the `u.Affiliation` to the query? I'm not requesting a larger dataset, just adding a field to it. I know the field is fine as it appears in phpMyAdmin, but I can't run the SQL successfully in phpMyAdmin either (I know from the past that phpMyAdmin times out on large queries that still work in PHP)

I have also tried adding:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

If I narrow the records returned by adding `u.LastName LIKE 'B%'` to the WHERE clause - it returns the desired results... so is there a restriction on the number of records returned?

Comment: Since I cannot offer any support with the timeout.  I would like to ask about the query.  What is going on with `completed`?  I've never seen a parenthetical expression like that in a SELECT.  LIKE is notoriously nasty regarding speed.  You should be able to move `e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%'` to the WHERE clause.  If you tune up query, doesn't it get you around the timeout?

Comment: Does `(e.UserName IS NOT NULL)` just convert `completed` values from NULL to an empty string?  Can you just make this a permanent adjustment in the table and omit it from the query?

Comment: the `e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%' has to stay there due to the query search on EnrollmentsTbl only appears if a record exist and if not the left join shows alternate results`

Comment: @mickmackusa Moving `e.ClassName LIKE 'Word%` to the WHERE clause would convert the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Comment: yes, I need the LEFT JOIN to accomplish my results. Like I said my query is fine without the addition of the Affiliation field. - I am getting desired results.

Comment: If your query (7 seconds or failure) or database table is beyond reproach, I wish you good luck with the timeout.

Comment: see my update above: if I add `u.LastName LIKE 'B%'` (narrow the number of results) it works?

Comment: Perhaps packet size? `max_allowed_packet`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583352/php-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: any idea where I would find that on a hosted site with cpanel? or even if I can override it?

Comment: Looks like a no go.  https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-increase-max_allowed_packet.361521/